# Conditional jQuery plugin call

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript

It might be a stupid question but I am not very up to date with some JavaScript techniques and I am wondering which would be the way to deal with jQuery plugins and their respective calls.

If I am calling a plugin in a JavaScript file when I am not actually importing it, I get an error like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tipsy'

Is there any way to avoid these kind of errors in the case I don't want to use the plugin even I am calling it?

In many cases I am using one only `.js` file in which I call many jQuery plugins but in some pages they are used and the elements or selectors they are using, they don't either exist.

I conditionally load or not the plugins depending on whether I am gonna use them or not, but my own `.js` file still having calls to them. (like if they were not used functions inside a JS file)

I have done it sometimes checking if the selector exist and then calling the pluging:

```
if($('.listWrap').length){
    //call the the plugin
   $('.listWrap').tipsy(....); 
}
```

But it doesn't look too good and can become bigger when using many plugins with many different selectors.

Which is the correct way to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You actually may be better off just including all of the plugins on every page, combined into a single file and minified.

You'll have fewer requests to the server; that one file will be cached as you go from page to page (instead of individual files loading on each page view); and these errors will go away without you needing to write new code.